# Значение слова "порядка" в определённом контексте

Tags: значения, выбор-слова

В одном тексте есть следующая фраза:

> *Порядка 10% (россиян) проходили обучающие онлайн-курсы*

Каково значение слова **порядка** в этом контексте? Я бы догадался, что оно такое же как "около". Но *порядок* переводится как *"order"* or *"sequence"* по-английски, и причём оно в родительном падеже.

Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: On the order of; in the ballpark of. "Around", basically.

Comment: =~ **Roughly speaking**, _10 percent_ (of Russian residents) took online training courses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this word means ["approximately"](https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0+10), ["about"](https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0). It is a [preposition](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0) and it comes from gen.sg. of the word "порядок", which happens to be used as a term in maths [(exponential form)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C).

Answer (score 3):

`Порядок` means "order of magnitude" here or just "around".

Of course, I don't think they meant strict mathematical meaning, but it's fair to assume it means between 3% and 30% of russans participated in online courses.